# MySQL perfomance testing transaction

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2013, transactions

I have c# project, that adds records to my users database. It adds user, some details about him, some posts etc. So I decided to add whole user instance through 
one transaction. It looks like this :

```
tr = conn.BeginTransaction();
addUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
addUserDetails.ExecuteNonQuery();
addPost.ExecuteNonQuery();
tr.Commit();
```

Now i want to check time of execution of my insert. And I don't know where i must check it. I have two variants:

```
tr = conn.BeginTransaction();
watch1.Start();
addUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
addUserDetails.ExecuteNonQuery();
addPost.ExecuteNonQuery();
watch1.Stop();
watch2.Start();
tr.Commit();
watch2.Stop();
```

Can you help me and explain which watch will stand for what?

EDIT: My queries are just simple inserts : Insert into (...) values (...)

Comment: The watch1 measures the time of executions and the watch2 measures the commit time.

Comment: @Tim3880 What do you mean by time of execution? My query is just Insert into user(...) values(...). But before I commit, values arent inserted into db. So about what execution are you saying?

Comment: Time of executions is the time used to complete your queries, to send data to sever, for server to process the data, for server to make changes. It happens before commit.

Comment: @Tim3880 Can you explain what does it mean "complete queries" if data is inserted only after transaction?

Comment: I think you misunderstood transaction. Depends on isolation level, many things are already done before commit.

Comment: @Tim3880 Then what happens when i commit transaction? Data inserts into db? Then what query did? I just need to understand which watch i must check, or maybe i must even summ them?

Comment: Yes you need sum them up for the whole transaction. For more information about transactions, you can consult the document.